# Are there any problems with my circuit design?

Tags: circuit-analysis, design, circuit-design, diy, home-automation

I am new to designing circuits but I have spent a lot of time researching for this project. I have been designing an automated indoor garden for my home. To save space, there will be 3 gardens stacked vertically. The gardens will be self watering using moisture sensors, a pump and solenoid valves. It will also have blue and red LEDs to provide light to the plants.

Here is the link to a google doc of my project for more details:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jLP35pS16meeRFSbU6V1jtvDDfdHTNM6jPjyyabYSCg/edit?usp=sharing

I have made my circuit using an electronic circuit simulator I found online. Here is the link to it:

[Circuit](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.0000049999999999999996+0.20306040966347483+50+20+50%0Av+208+176+208+128+0+0+40+20+0+0+0.5%0Ar+400+112+400+160+0+150%0Ar+496+0+496+64+0+1%0Ar+560+0+560+64+0+1%0Aw+208+0+400+0+0%0Aw+208+176+208+304+0%0Aw+496+0+560+0+0%0As+368+-96+368+-64+0+0+false%0A162+496+80+496+128+1+12+0+1+0+0.6%0A162+560+80+560+128+1+12+0+1+0+0.6%0A162+624+80+624+128+1+12+0+1+0+0.6%0Aw+560+0+624+0+0%0Ar+624+0+624+64+0+1%0Aw+400+288+400+304+0%0Aw+560+256+560+304+0%0Aw+624+256+624+304+0%0Aw+496+256+496+304+0%0Aw+624+304+560+304+0%0Aw+560+304+496+304+0%0Aw+208+304+400+304+0%0Ar+400+32+400+80+0+50%0At+368+208+400+208+0+1+0.6419268978578376+0.6890430707819402+100%0Aw+208+128+208+0+1%0Aw+368+-32+368+208+0%0Av+368+-144+368+-96+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ag+368+-144+368+-160+0%0Aw+368+-64+368+-32+2%0Ag+208+176+176+176+0%0Aw+528+-64+528+-32+2%0Ag+528+-144+528+-160+0%0Av+528+-144+528+-96+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+528+-32+528+176+0%0At+528+176+560+176+0+1+-2.5851068149069443+0.7359478991358257+100%0As+528+-96+528+-64+0+0+false%0As+464+-96+464+-64+0+0+false%0At+464+176+496+176+0+1+-2.5851068149069167+0.7359478991358257+100%0Aw+464+-32+464+176+0%0Av+464+-144+464+-96+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ag+464+-144+464+-160+0%0Aw+464+-64+464+-32+2%0Aw+496+64+496+80+0%0Aw+496+304+400+304+0%0Aw+400+0+496+0+0%0Aw+400+32+400+0+0%0Aw+400+80+400+112+0%0Ar+400+224+400+288+0+50%0Aw+400+160+400+192+0%0Ax+407+169+448+172+4+16+Pump%0Aw+496+128+496+160+0%0Ar+496+192+496+256+0+7%0Aw+560+64+560+80+0%0Aw+560+128+560+160+0%0Ar+560+192+560+256+0+7%0Aw+624+64+624+80+3%0Ar+624+192+624+256+0+7%0Aw+624+128+624+160+0%0At+592+176+624+176+0+1+-2.5851068149069345+0.7359478991358257+100%0Aw+592+-32+592+176+0%0As+592+-96+592+-64+0+0+false%0Av+592+-144+592+-96+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ag+592+-144+592+-160+0%0Aw+592+-64+592+-32+2%0Aw+624+0+672+0+0%0Aw+800+304+800+352+0%0Aw+944+304+944+352+0%0Aw+1088+304+1088+352+0%0A162+800+64+800+112+1+3.4+0+0+1+0.5%0A162+800+112+800+160+1+3.4+0+0+1+0.5%0A162+800+160+800+208+1+3.4+0+0+1+0.5%0A162+800+256+800+304+1+3.4+0+0+1+0.5%0A162+800+208+800+256+1+3.4+0+0+1+0.5%0Ar+800+0+800+64+0+7%0Ar+880+0+880+64+0+1.3%0Aw+880+0+800+0+0%0A162+880+64+880+112+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+880+160+880+208+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+880+112+880+160+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+880+304+880+352+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+880+352+880+400+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+880+256+880+304+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+880+208+880+256+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+880+400+880+448+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0Aw+1024+0+944+0+0%0Ar+1024+0+1024+64+0+1.3%0Ar+944+0+944+64+0+7%0A162+944+208+944+256+1+3.4+0+0+1+0.5%0A162+944+256+944+304+1+3.4+0+0+1+0.5%0A162+944+160+944+208+1+3.4+0+0+1+0.5%0A162+944+112+944+160+1+3.4+0+0+1+0.5%0A162+944+64+944+112+1+3.4+0+0+1+0.5%0Aw+880+0+944+0+0%0Aw+1024+0+1088+0+0%0A162+1088+64+1088+112+1+3.4+0+0+1+0.5%0A162+1088+112+1088+160+1+3.4+0+0+1+0.5%0A162+1088+160+1088+208+1+3.4+0+0+1+0.5%0A162+1088+256+1088+304+1+3.4+0+0+1+0.5%0A162+1088+208+1088+256+1+3.4+0+0+1+0.5%0Ar+1088+0+1088+64+0+7%0Ar+1168+0+1168+64+0+1.3%0Aw+1168+0+1088+0+0%0A162+880+448+880+496+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+1168+448+1168+496+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+1168+400+1168+448+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+1168+208+1168+256+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+1168+256+1168+304+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+1168+352+1168+400+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+1168+304+1168+352+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+1168+112+1168+160+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+1168+160+1168+208+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+1168+64+1168+112+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+1024+448+1024+496+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+1024+400+1024+448+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+1024+208+1024+256+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+1024+256+1024+304+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+1024+352+1024+400+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+1024+304+1024+352+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+1024+112+1024+160+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+1024+160+1024+208+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0A162+1024+64+1024+112+1+2.2+1+0+0+0.5%0Aw+1088+352+1088+496+0%0Aw+1088+496+1024+496+0%0Aw+944+352+944+496+0%0Aw+944+496+1024+496+0%0Aw+944+496+880+496+0%0Aw+880+496+800+496+0%0Aw+800+400+800+496+0%0Aw+752+0+800+0+0%0Ap+1248+0+1248+496+1+0%0Aw+1248+496+1168+496+0%0Aw+1248+0+1168+0+0%0Aw+736+432+800+496+0%0As+752+0+672+0+0+0+false%0A370+800+352+800+400+1+0%0A370+736+432+624+304+1+0%0Ax+637+132+675+135+4+16+Valve%0A370+1168+496+1088+496+1+0%0Ax+219+372+492+375+4+16+Valve:%5CsForward%5CsVoltage%5Cs%5Cq%5Cs12V,%5CsI%5Cs%5Cq%5Cs0.6A%0Ax+217+397+439+400+4+16+Pump:%5CsVoltage%5Cs%5Cq%5Cs12V,%5CsI%5Cs%5Cq%5Cs0.08A%0Ax+218+424+677+427+4+16+Blue%5CsLEDs:%5CsForward%5CsVoltage%5Cs%5Cq%5Cs3-3.4,%5CsForward%5CsCurrent%5Cs%5Cq%5Cs0.4-0.5A%0Ax+218+453+684+456+4+16+Red%5CsLEDs:%5CsForward%5CsVoltage%5Cs%5Cq%5Cs2-2.2V,%5CsForward%5CsCurrent%5Cs%5Cq%5Cs0.4-0.5A%0Ax+218+482+437+485+4+16+Power%5CsSupply:%5CsV%5Cs%5Cq%5Cs20V,%5CsI%5Cq4.5A%0A)

[image]

As you can see, I am using 1 pump, 3 solenoid valves (indicated by the green light), 15 blue LEDs, 27 red LEDs, and a laptop charger as the power supply(20V, 4.5A). To control the pump and valves, I am using transistors and an Arduino UNO.

The idea is that the moisture sensors will detect when each level of the garden needs to be watered. When a level of the garden is too dry, the Arduino will send power to the pump to turn it on. The Arduino will also send power to a specific valve to allow water to flow to that level of the garden.

Component Data:

[Transistors](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/603008/CDIL/2N2222A.html)

[Valves](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/191921893492)

[Pump](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Gikfun-12V-DC-Dosing-Pump-Peristaltic-Dosing-Head-with-Connector-For-Arduino-Aquarium-Lab-Analytic-Diy/32725118884.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.0.itI3F5)

[LEDs](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/50pcs-lot-LED-Grow-Light-Diode-LED-Beads-3W-Grow-Leds-Deep-Red-Blue-High-Power/32713220189.html?spm=2114.13010208.99999999.264.lnXSF8)

So the question is, can anyone see any problems with the circuit before I actually build it? I am pretty new to electronics so I am worried I am going to damage some of my components.

A more specific question I had was, am I representing my pump correctly in the simulation? I have used a resistor to represent it. Should I be using a diode like I did for my valves?

Please let me know if I need to provide more information. Any feed back I receive will be greatly appreciated! :)

***UPDATE***

Thank you for all your wonderful suggestions! :)
I have used your suggestions to change a few things. I am splitting the watering and lighting portions up into 2 separate circuits, each with their own power source. The watering side will be using a 12V power source, while the LEDs will have a 20V power source. Using separate power supplies also gives me the option to add additional levels to my garden in the future since I no longer have to worry about going over my power supply current rating.

Here is the link to the updated [simulation of the watering circuit](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.0000049999999999999996+0.0129812176855438+38+20+50%0Av+208+176+208+128+0+0+40+12+0+0+0.5%0Ar+304+32+304+128+0+150%0Aw+208+0+304+0+0%0Aw+208+176+208+304+0%0Aw+448+0+592+0+0%0As+272+-96+272+-64+0+0+false%0Aw+592+0+736+0+0%0Aw+592+224+592+304+0%0Aw+736+224+736+304+0%0Aw+448+224+448+304+0%0Aw+736+304+592+304+0%0Aw+592+304+448+304+0%0Aw+208+304+304+304+0%0At+272+208+304+208+0+1+0.6860222667683417+0.7031728698786751+100%0Aw+208+128+208+0+1%0Aw+272+-32+272+32+0%0Av+272+-144+272+-96+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ag+272+-144+272+-160+0%0Aw+272+-64+272+-32+2%0Ag+208+176+176+176+0%0Aw+560+-64+560+-32+2%0Ag+560+-144+560+-160+0%0Av+560+-144+560+-96+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+560+-32+560+32+0%0At+560+208+592+208+0+1+0.6825101757767589+0.7385413773120101+100%0As+560+-96+560+-64+0+0+false%0As+416+-96+416+-64+0+0+false%0At+416+208+448+208+0+1+0.6825101757767581+0.7385413773120099+100%0Aw+416+-32+416+32+0%0Av+416+-144+416+-96+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ag+416+-144+416+-160+0%0Aw+416+-64+416+-32+2%0Aw+448+304+304+304+0%0Aw+304+0+448+0+0%0Ar+272+32+272+208+0+100%0Ax+313+152+354+155+4+16+Pump%0Ar+416+32+416+208+0+100%0Ar+560+32+560+208+0+100%0Ar+704+32+704+208+0+100%0At+704+208+736+208+0+1+0.6825101757767571+0.73854137731201+100%0Aw+704+-32+704+32+0%0As+704+-96+704+-64+0+0+false%0Av+704+-144+704+-96+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ag+704+-144+704+-160+0%0Aw+704+-64+704+-32+2%0Ax+744+151+781+154+4+16+Valve%0Ax+219+372+485+375+4+16+Valve:%5CsForward%5CsVoltage%5Cs%5Cq%5Cs12V,%5CsI%5Cs%5Cq%5Cs0.6A%0Ax+217+397+433+400+4+16+Pump:%5CsVoltage%5Cs%5Cq%5Cs12V,%5CsI%5Cs%5Cq%5Cs0.08A%0Ax+218+424+667+427+4+16+Blue%5CsLEDs:%5CsForward%5CsVoltage%5Cs%5Cq%5Cs3-3.4,%5CsForward%5CsCurrent%5Cs%5Cq%5Cs0.4-0.5A%0Ax+218+453+674+456+4+16+Red%5CsLEDs:%5CsForward%5CsVoltage%5Cs%5Cq%5Cs2-2.2V,%5CsForward%5CsCurrent%5Cs%5Cq%5Cs0.4-0.5A%0Ax+218+346+417+349+4+16+Power%5CsSupply:%5CsV%5Cs%5Cq%5Cs12V,%5CsI%5Cq5A%0Aw+304+224+304+304+0%0Ar+448+32+448+128+0+20%0Ar+592+32+592+128+0+20%0Ar+736+32+736+128+0+20%0Ax+599+149+636+152+4+16+Valve%0Ax+456+152+493+155+4+16+Valve%0Ap+144+0+144+304+1+0%0Aw+208+304+144+304+0%0Aw+208+0+144+0+0%0Ad+352+128+352+32+1+0.805904783%0Ad+496+128+496+32+1+0.805904783%0Ad+640+128+640+32+1+0.805904783%0Ad+784+128+784+32+1+0.805904783%0Aw+304+0+304+32+0%0Aw+304+32+352+32+0%0Aw+352+128+304+128+0%0Aw+304+128+304+192+0%0Aw+448+0+448+32+0%0Aw+448+32+496+32+0%0Aw+496+128+448+128+0%0Aw+448+128+448+192+0%0Aw+592+0+592+32+0%0Aw+592+32+640+32+0%0Aw+640+128+592+128+0%0Aw+592+128+592+192+0%0Aw+736+192+736+128+0%0Aw+784+32+736+32+0%0Aw+784+128+736+128+0%0Aw+736+32+736+0+0%0A)

I am going to wait until my LEDs arrive in the mail before I design my circuit for them. Since they are from china, I want to test them to see what their specifications actually are. I am also looking into current regulators for them.

Comment: Can you add a proper circuit diagram and one that doesn't have moving symbols all over it. Naming components and providing data sheet links to components is also highly recommended if you want decent answers.

Comment: Next time, check out how to insert links and insert images as well.

Comment: You need resistors in the base leads of the transistors - 1K or so may do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Simulating the pump: A resistor is not a bad way to model the pump in this case since it will just be on or off.  More accurately it would be modeled as an inductor with series resistance, but I wouldn't bother in this case.  Mind you I'm not sure how much value there is in simulating any of this circuit as it's fairly straightforward to calculate current draw and voltages.  It's actually more accurate to model the valve as a resistor also instead of the diode.
2. Why did you put the 50 and 7 Ohm resistors on the emitter side of the transistors?  You should put those on the collector side to make sure the transistors saturate when turned on.  The series resistor would 100 Ohms for the pump ((20-12)/0.08) and it looks like you split it into 50 on top and 50 on bottom.  I don't see why.  You did something similar for the valves, but here you added 1 Ohm and 7 Ohms for some reason.  I think because the valve is modeled as a diode which adds voltage drop.  Just do that the same ways as the pump, and again put the resistance in the top side.  It would be much better if you could use a 12V supply so you can drive the pump and valves directly, rather than using series resistors which will get hot and waste power.  That would require more LED chains, but that should not be a big problem.
3. The transistors need resistors at the base terminal as Peter mentioned.
4. You should include flyback diodes on the valves and pump to avoid damaging the transistors.
5. The LEDs: Assuming you stay with 20V, the 7 Ohm resistor for the Blue chains is probably OK, but I think the 1.3 Ohm resistor for the Red ones is probably too small.  It's hard to accurately simulate LEDs like this.  I would start with a higher value resistor and measure the current before reducing the resistor value.  Otherwise you might overdrive your LEDs and possibly damage them.  If you use a lower voltage supply, you would need to reduce the number of LEDs and recalculate the resistors, but again, start with higher values until you get actual readings.  Ideally you should use constant current LED drivers, but if you use the resistors, make sure they are rated for the power they will dissipate.  [This](http://led.linear1.org/led.wiz) is a pretty cool LED array designer that might help.

Comment: Note that the red LEDs, if their voltage is 2 volts rather than 2.2, will draw 1.5 amps per string, while if the blues are 3 rather than 3.4 they will draw 0.7 amps per string. and the power supply will to into current limit.

Comment: Thank you for all the great suggestions! I really appreciate it!
I have taken your advice and updated the parts for the motor and valves. I still need to do some research to figure out how to add your suggestion for flyback diodes on the valves and pump.
Here is the link to my [updated design](http://tinyurl.com/hvtdl6q)

[Split comments up into 2 parts due to char restrictions]

Comment: The calculation you showed me to find the resistor value for the pump worked really well. However, when I tried to do the same from the valves, it didn't seem to work out.
I did (20-12)/0.6 = 13.3ohms. When I add a 13 ohm resistor to the circuit, my current is only 427mA when it should be 600mA and the voltage drop is only 8.55V when it should be 12V. I am not sure why. Does it have to do with the value of the resistor before my transistor? How do I figure out what value my resistor should be before my transistor?

Comment: You should measure the voltage drop across the transistor (collector to emitter).  It should only be about 0.2V.  If it's higher then it's not saturated and it will be dissipating more heat than it needs to.  You said "Does it have to do with the value of the resistor before my transistor?"  Do you still have two resistors, or only one now above the transistor?

Comment: I had only one resistor on the base side of the transistor (1k ohm).  The voltage drop across the transistor (collector to emitter) was 6V. I changed the resistor from 1k ohm to 100 ohm and the Vce is now 56mV. That also fixed my problem in my second comment. The 13 ohm resistor in series with 20 ohm resistor(the valve) now gives me the correct current can voltage drop. Thank a lot!

Comment: Great.  I'm surprised 1k in the base wasn't enough given the 5V source, but glad you figured it out.

Comment: So I have been trying to redesign everything to use a 12V power source instead of 20V as per your suggestion. I am running into a problem with the LEDs. I can't reduce the number of LEDs or else my plants won't have enough light to grow. Using a voltage of 12, I have to put more LEDs in parallel compared to my first design. The problem with this is that they will require more current. My power supply can only provide 5A. Any ideas?

Comment: Right with the reduced voltage you would need more chains as I mentioned, but the current would increase because the total power doesn't change.  P = V * I  So if 4.5A at 20V was sufficient before (P = 90W), with 12V you would need to supply 7.5A to deliver the same power (assuming all the same power losses).  You might need some extra because there would be more LED resistors, but the point of changing to 12V was to remove the resistors for the pump and valves, so it may work out being less.

Comment: So you could increase the power supply rating, or just add a second one for part of the lights.  For that matter, could you keep 20V for the LEDs, and just use 12V for the pump and valves?

Comment: Unfortunately I can only find a reasonably priced 12V power supply with a maximum of 5A. If I was to use 2 power supplies,  20V supply for my lights and a 12V supply for my pumps and valves, would the overall power consumption of everything actually be less than using one 20V supply? If so, I think that's what I will do.

Since this is a vertical garden, this will also allow me to add additional levels to my garden since I will have more capacity(can still draw more current) for my power supplies. Each additional level would add another valve and another set of LEDs.

Comment: I have a basic question about grounding my circuit. In the simulation diagram I posted, you can see that I added a ground at the end of my circuit. When I wire this up in real life, what would my ground be?

Comment: If you have two supplies, the total power should be less than your original design with the resistors in series with the pump and valves.  The ground doesn't need to be connected to anything, but it's common to tie it to the mains ground.  I.e. presumably the power supplies will be powered from mains and if there is a ground wire, you can tie it to that assuming the power supply is isolated.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about the ground. What do you mean by "mains ground"?
I am plugging my power supplies into an wall outlet. My power supplies have 2 wires connecting to my circuit, a positive and a negative.

If I was to wire my circuit up in real life as shown in the original picture without the ground would it work?

Comment: The wall power is called 'mains'.  You can use it without ground.  It's mainly for safety, but your voltages are low enough that it's not essential.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I don't need a ground? I can wire up the positive end of my power supply to one terminal of my pump and the other terminal of the pump can connect to the negative of the power supply?

Comment: Yes, if you are not using the transistors.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

For your 4th suggestion about the flyback diodes, where should I add the diodes to my circuit? I would be adding 4. One for each valve, and one for the pump.

Should the diode go after my transistor on the emitter side? 
Should the diode go before my transistor on the base side?
Should the diode go before my transistor on the collector side and before my pump? 
Or should it go somewhere else?

Comment: Regardless of where you wire the device (pump or valve) the diode should always be in parallel with it, with the cathode connected to the positive terminal.

Comment: Solution 0: 9 x 3 array uses 27 LEDs exactly
    +-|>|-|>|-|>|-|>|-|>|-|>|-|>|-|>|-|>|--/\/\/-+  R = 1 ohms
    +-|>|-|>|-|>|-|>|-|>|-|>|-|>|-|>|-|>|--/\/\/-+  R = 1 ohms
    +-|>|-|>|-|>|-|>|-|>|-|>|-|>|-|>|-|>|--/\/\/-+  R = 1 ohms

The wizard says: In solution 0:
  each 1 ohm resistor dissipates 250 mW
  the wizard thinks ½W resistors are needed for your application
  together, all resistors dissipate 750 mW
  together, the diodes dissipate 29700 mW              
  total power dissipated by the array is 30450 mW      
  the array draws current of 1500 mA from the source.

Comment: Using the link you gave me for a cool LED array designer, the above is what I got for the red LEDs.
I input 20V as the source voltage, 2.2 as the diode forward voltage, 500mA as the diode forward current, and said to use 27 LEDs.
Before you told be that you didnt think I should use such low resistance values. However, this wizard is suggesting to use 1ohm resistors. Do you think this is ok?

Comment: I thought about it some more and in your case I'm not as concerned about low values.  The current is fairly high, so even a 1 Ohm resistor will produce a 0.5V drop.  I was concerned that a low value would result in higher intensity fluctuations as the diode voltages change.  The low value resistors should OK, but keep in mind that you are more likely to need to try different values to get the intensity you want, especially since there will be some resistance in the wires and connections.  I would start with something like 5-10 Ohms, and reduce it until I got the current I wanted.

Comment: Higher value resistors will need higher power ratings also, e.g. 10 Ohm at 5W, 5 Ohm at 2W, 2 Ohm at 1W.

Comment: I bought some variable resistors. They should allow me to get the exact resistance I want. They only have a power rating of 0.5W though.
[Data Sheet](https://www.nidec-copal-electronics.com/e/catalog/trimmer/ct-6.pdf)

Comment: What resistance?  If they go higher than ~2 Ohms, the pot will probably get damaged because the power would be too high.  As the resistance goes up, the current will drop, so the power will go down, but it's hard to predict what the actual current will be for any given resistance, so the current may not go down enough to prevent the power dissipated by the resistor from going up.  The resistor power is I^2*R.

Comment: I think I see your point. I bought 4 potentiometers with resistances of 50, 200, 500, 1000 ohms. The power rating for them are 0.5W. For the LEDs, the current could be as high as 0.5A. If I put the 50 ohm potentiometer in series, the max resistance I can set it to would be 2 ohms from this equation. P=I^2*R; 0.5=0.5^2*R; R=2. So can I use this potentiometer set to 1-2 ohms in series with my red LEDs? Im not sure what I am going to do about my blue LEDs since they will need a higher resistance value.

Comment: I would get a number of 0.5 or 1 Ohm fixed power resistors, and solder them in series, with one end tied to ground.  You can then connect the LED string to the junction between each resistor (starting from the end with the total resistance).  Each step you move it up you can check intensity and current until you find the value that works for you.